# CreateProcess from python results in "OSError: [WinError 87] The parameter is incorrect"

Tags: python, windows, subprocess, virtualenv, createprocess

I have a python program that runs another program as a subprocess. It works fine on linux/mac but on windows I get the following error:

```
OSError: [WinError 87] The parameter is incorrect
```

From Googling I find various explanations for how to fix it in particular apps but not explanation for what it means.

---

The line that the errors comes from looks a bit like the following where `venv` is a virtualenv that poetry was installed into, but the virtualenv is not activated.

```py
Popen(['D:\\...\\venv\\Scripts\\poetry.exe', 'install'])
```

**What's going wrong here?  What does this error actually mean?**

---

**Update:** The following extract shows exactly where the error is thrown inside the stdlib.

```py
>           hp, ht, pid, tid = _winapi.CreateProcess(executable, args,
                                     # no special security
                                     None, None,
                                     int(not close_fds),
                                     creationflags,
                                     env,
                                     cwd,
                                     startupinfo)
E                                    OSError: [WinError 87] The parameter is incorrect

C:\hostedtoolcache\windows\Python\3.9.13\x64\lib\subprocess.py:1420: OSError
```

Full execution output can be found here: https://github.com/nat-n/poethepoet/actions/runs/3211595138/jobs/5249871870

Comment: Does it work if you try it manually in cmd ?

Comment: @Sheyteo, the tricky part is that the only windows env I have to test this on right now the windows container on GitHub CI, so it's hard to say. The pip installed binary  is generally known to work. My suspicion is that not having activated the venv is somehow a problem... (only on windows though). Still my question is about what the error means.

Comment: Please post the whole code and the traceback. [\[SO\]: How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example (reprex (mcve))](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @CristiFati Sure, I added details of exactly where the error originates in the stdlib. I'm afraid I'm running this in pytest in a CI environment so don't have a full stack trace, though I don't know if it would help much. The code on my side that's calling the Popen is quite abstract so I think the single line I gave illustrates best what I'm doing.

Comment: The line you shown can't possibly trigger that error. How long is the 1st arg? what about `os.getcwd()`? What;s the *Python* version?

Comment: @CristiFati Added a link to the full output. The cwd is explicitly being set to where I want poetry to run, which is not in the vicinity of the venv containing the executable. 
The first arg passed to Popen is only slightly longer than what I've shown.
Why would the cwd matter? 
What makes you certain the `OSError` is not thrown by `_winapi.CreateProcess`?

Comment: It's not *OSError* in general, but this particular one (87).

Comment: https://github.com/nat-n/poethepoet/commit/b3490be73fb2307a11e183f9a0890cfb3deb28ba fixed this?

Comment: I managed to solve my problem, though I’m still curious what this error actually means.